# Modifying Query-InsecureLDAPBinds.ps1

Tags: windows, powershell

Trying to figure out how to add a time variable this script found at

https://github.com/russelltomkins/Active-Directory/blob/master/Query-InsecureLDAPBinds.ps1

I tried toss in variations of `$Time = $eventXML.event.System.TimeCreatedSystemTime` under the line for $user but haven't had any luck, and I'm not sure how to get this info added in. I also added the following under $Row.User = $User

```
$Row.Time = $Time





 # Prepare Variables
    Param (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0)][String]$ComputerName = "localhost",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)][Int]$Hours = 24)

    # Create an Array to hold our returnedvValues
    $InsecureLDAPBinds = @()

    # Grab the appropriate event entries
    $Events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Directory Service';Id=2889; StartTime=(get-date).AddHours("-$Hours")}

    # Loop through each event and output the 
    ForEach ($Event in $Events) { 
        $eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()

        # Build Our Values
        $Client = ($eventXML.event.EventData.Data[0])
        $IPAddress = $Client.SubString(0,$Client.LastIndexOf(":")) #Accomodates for IPV6 Addresses
        $Port = $Client.SubString($Client.LastIndexOf(":")+1) #Accomodates for IPV6 Addresses
        $User = $eventXML.event.EventData.Data[1]
        Switch ($eventXML.event.EventData.Data[2])
            {
            0 {$BindType = "Unsigned"}
            1 {$BindType = "Simple"}
            }

        # Add Them To a Row in our Array
        $Row = "" | select IPAddress,Port,User,BindType
        $Row.IPAddress = $IPAddress
        $Row.Port = $Port
        $Row.User = $User
        $Row.BindType = $BindType

        # Add the row to our Array
        $InsecureLDAPBinds += $Row
    }
    # Dump it all out to a CSV.
    Write-Host $InsecureLDAPBinds.Count "records saved to .\InsecureLDAPBinds.csv for Domain Controller" $ComputerName
    $InsecureLDAPBinds | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation .\InsecureLDAPBinds.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it in the event itself without parsing the XML:

```
$Time = $Event.TimeCreated
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.